# "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" when collecting data from truncated data from an API (json)

Tags: python

So, I'm trying to decompress data using Python but some data in the API are too long, and is truncated. So whenever I try get the information it comes up with this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/API + Python.py", line 6, in <module>
    accessoryData = skyblockData['profiles']['1']['members']['79e1532d994640799ff709edf5286a31']['talisman_bag']['data']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Here is my code:

```
import gzip
import requests as r
hypixelData = r.get('https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=*API KEY*&name=CraftYun83').json()
uuid = hypixelData['player']['uuid']
skyblockData = r.get('https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/profiles?key=*API KEY*&uuid='+uuid).json()
accessoryData = skyblockData['profiles']['1']['members']['79e1532d994640799ff709edf5286a31']['talisman_bag']['data']
s = gzip.decompress(accessoryData)
print(s)
```

Here is what the truncated text looks like:

[image: Truncated text]

[image: Truncated and untruncated text]

*edit*
After @Barmar has answered, the issue was that I put 1 in quotes. but after that, it said that the gzip decompressor needed bytes not str, so I made them into bytes, with utf-8 encoding.
but then it came back with this error...

```
gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'H4')
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback in your post.

Comment: Just guessing, but `['1']` should probably be `[1]`

Comment: Done, but I'm not quite sure how that's gonna help since I mentioned why this was happening but ok.

Comment: If the data were truncated you would get an error from `.json()`

Comment: It's hard to tell which index it's complaining about. Try accessing each level in a separate statement so that you can see which part gets the error.